# Sas PROC EXPORT xlsx without named ranges

Tags: sas, export, xlsx

how Can I use PROC Export and obtain excel file without named ranges?

I've got something like this now:

```
proc export 
  data=WORK.INFO
  dbms=xlsx 
  outfile=&fn
  replace;
  sheet="INFO";
  putnames=no;
run;
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Is the auto-created named range a deal breaker? If so, you might try something like ods excel.

Comment: Sadly PowerBI see only null values when I'm trying to import data obtained from sas with named ranges. After deleting named ranges in excel, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need output without headers, PROC REPORT is the way to go.

```
ods _all_ close;
ods excel file=&fn. options(sheet_name="INFO");
title;
proc report data=WORK.INFO nowd noheader;
run;

ods excel close;
/* Then Re-enable whatever ods destinations you want active */
```